# Is it possible to make a dictionary with 'multiple raster' variables?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, remote-sensing

Working in QGIS 2.14, I'm making a script to prepare images for remote sensing classifications. The user is prompted to enter multiple rasters for each band. I would like these rasters to be organized into a dictionary so each band can be prepared in loop.

```
##Prepare Band Images = name
##Band01 = multiple raster
##Band02 = multiple raster

dictionary = {
   "band01": Band01,
   "band02": Band02
}

for bandidx, bandfiles in dictionary.items():
   # Prepare band images
```

My issue is that the above script produces the following error message:

[image]

Is it possible to have a dictionary with 'multiple raster' variables in it? Alternatively, is there an easier way to make a list of 'multiple raster' variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the spaces in the variable definition

With

```
##Band01 = multiple raster
```

Band01 is not defined (the variable name is Band01 + space), whereas with

```
##Band01= multiple raster
```

There's no problem

Comment: I'd suggest that is a bug. The [processing script code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py#L158) should do a `.strip()` on all tokens.  Probably not worth reporting though as 3.0 changes the processing scripts completely.